# Hide few permissions from UI (Edit Permissions Dialog)

Tags: c#, typescript, user-interface, asp.net-core-3.1, serenity-platform

How to hide few permissions from UI

> Administration -> Roles -> `Role` -> Edit Permissions -> `Edit Permission Dialog`
>
> Administration -> Users-> `User` -> Edit Permissions -> `Edit Permission Dialog`

Answer (score 0):

in your `RoleDialog.ts` hide the button with

```
protected updateInterface() {
   super.updateInterface();
   this.toolbar.findButton("edit-permissions-button").hide();
}
```

but you may want to keep it active for admin user by checking

```
if (!Authorization.userDefinition.IsAdmin) {
 ... hide it
}
```

Comment: I don't want button to hide. Few permissions in the list.

Comment: it's not clear what your question is, can you clarify what you need to do?